# PHP get sum of SQL table

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I have MAMP (local hosted SQL,WEB etc server) the database name is :NKTDEBITS the table name is :Insurance  and the column on the table is STATECOV. I know I'm close with this but still get a black in the field that should generate the total, anyone got a idea?

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","KNTDebits");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Insurance");
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Office");
    $result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM RichmondLocation");
    $result4 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM DanvilleLocation");
    $result5 = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(STATECOV) AS STATECOV_sum FROM Insurance'); 


    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Truck Number</th>
    <th>VIN</th>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>State Coverage</th>
    <th>Comprehinsive Coverage</th>
    <th>Property Damage/th>
    <th>Personal Injury</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['TNUM'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['VIN'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['MAKE'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['MODEL'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['STATECOV'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['COMPRE'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['PROPDMG'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['PRSINJ'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";


    //Table 2 Start
    str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5); // adds 5 spaces
    echo "<table border='5'>

    <tr>
    <th>Richmond</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Payment</th>
    <th>Payer</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
     {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row3[''] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row3['DATE'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row3['PAYMENT'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row3['PAYER'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";

    //Table 4 Start
    str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5); // adds 5 spaces
    echo "<table border='5'>

    <tr>
    <th>Danville</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Payment</th>
    <th>Payer</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row4[''] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row4['DATE'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row4['PAYMENT'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";

    //Table 5 Start

    echo "<table border='5'>

    <tr>
    <th>Total</th>
    </tr>";

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(STATECOV) AS value_sum FROM Insurance'); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    $sum = $row['value_sum'];

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";


    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You aren't passing a connection handle to mysql_query. You should also be using mysqli / pdo.

Comment: Get rid of the while loop in table 5 - it will allways be skipped, as you already have read the ionly row.

Comment: Don't mix and match MySQL and MySQLi

Comment: i didnt know that i was using MYSQLi as this was taking from others i researched. If i get rid of table 5's loop wont that kill any possibility of getting the SUM of the column?

Answer (score 0):

You need a GROUP BY to go along with your SUM.  I don;t know enough about you table to let you know what column you should use for this.

You should be handling potential error cases whenn you query the database, as you will quickly see when you are getting database/query errors.

You should also look to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: what about this (to kill the loop in table 5)       $result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(STATECOV) AS value_sum FROM Insurance'); 
//$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

Comment: $result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(STATECOV) AS value_sum FROM Insurance'); 
//$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";